# Musical term for singing and sobbing

Tags: vocabulary

What is the technical musical term for singing and sobbing at the same time? Can I say  singhiozzio?

Comment: I was not aware; this would be used in opera, but I don't consider operas written after 1805. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The usual way would be with a gerund, like *crescendo* or *diminuendo*.

So my bet is on *singhiozzando*, which seems to be confirmed in [*Rigoletto*](http://www.librettidopera.it/zpdf/rigoletto.pdf), p. 14:

[image: Excerpt from the opera Rigoletto, showing the word "singhiozzando" as an performance instruction.]

This word is defined in the [OnMusic Dictionary](https://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/3171-singhiozzando):

> ### singhiozzando
>
> [Italian, sobbing]
>
> A directive to perform the indicated passage of a composition with a sobbing effect, especially in vocal and string music where it can be marked by a strong portamento.